# What causes"***** Out of Package Error Occurred" in Standalone java JPA2.1 Application

Tags: java, hibernate, db2, jpa-2.1

I have a Java SE 1.7 standalone application.

It uses Hibernate 4.3 final and JPA 2.1 to retrieve thousands of rows from a db2 zos database.

I have a multiple tables tor retrieve related rows from.

All I am testing currently is retrieving the Parent Table rows then two related children table rows.
One child table has a one to one relationship the other has a One to Many relationship.

I can retrieve 2000+ rows from the main parent table OK, I hold these rows in a an `ArrayList`

Then I attempt to retrieve the children table rows using the Ids held in my array list.

This is when I generate the following exception:-

```
***** Out of Package Error Occurred (2015-01-14 15:55:29.935) *****


Concurrently open statements:
1. SQL string:  SELECT .....
   Number of statements:  1150
********************
```

My JPA entity classes do **not** have any Mappings between them e.g. `@ManyTo` or `@OneTo`

Heres my persistence.xml file

```
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="persistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>table.class.One</class>
        <class>table.class.Two</class>
        <class>table.class.Three</class>
        <properties>
            <!-- Configuring JDBC properties -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:db2://host:port/LOCATION:retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true;emulateParameterMetaDataForZCalls=1;" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pword" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="schema" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />

            <!-- Hibernate properties -->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2390Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class"
                value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />

            <!-- Configuring Connection Pool -->
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="500" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxStatementsPerConnection"
                value="10" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="2000" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout"
                value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces"
                value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

How can I get JPA and/or hibernate to "close" the open statements?